# Rails Enum, how to remove a value from the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

this is the first time I use rails enum.

I have in my app the user model with a role. To manage the role I use enum

```
enum professional_role: ProfessionalRole.all
```

ProfessionalRole is a class

```
 class ProfessionalRole
  def self.all
    %i(altro
       amministrazione
       segreteria
       buyer
       buyer_audiovideo_consumer_electronics_home_entertainment
       buyer_fotografia_photo
       buyer_grandi_elettrodomestici_mda_home_confort
       buyer_it_information_technology
       buyer_piccoli_elettrodomestici_sda
       buyer_telefonia_telecomunicazioni
       capi_area
       comunicazione_hr
       direzione
       marketing
       edp)
  end
 end
```

I need to remove some values from the array, of course I don't have users with that roles, but removing some values every user role is wrong, because I short the array. How can I solve it?

The unique way I find to solve is to save to a CSV the user and the roles, then modify the array and resave every user with his role from the CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums are stored as integers in the database. When you declare enums implicitly (without telling Rails what integer the value should be mapped to), Rails will guess that the first value is mapped to 0, the second to 1 and so on. Rails is therefore translating your code to the following hash:

```
{ altro: 0, amministrazione: 1, segreteria: 2, buyer: 3,
  buyer_audiovideo_consumer_electronics_home_entertainment: 4,
  buyer_fotografia_photo: 5,
  buyer_grandi_elettrodomestici_mda_home_confort: 6,
  buyer_it_information_technology: 7,
  buyer_piccoli_elettrodomestici_sda: 8,
  buyer_telefonia_telecomunicazioni: 9, capi_area: 10,
  comunicazione_hr: 11, direzione: 12, marketing: 13, edp: 14 }
```

If you then simply remove one of these items, Rails assumes that you know what you are doing. Say you remove `altro` in your enum, then it assumes that `amministrazione` should be mapped to 0, which obviously will be wrong. You still want it to be mapped to 1 but you no longer want to map 0 to anything. You could fix that with a search and replace in your database and decrement all the `professional_role` column with 1, but that is obsiously very cumbersome.

To fix this problem, you need to declare your enum explicitly and state what integer you want those values to be mapped to. Let's say you want to remove `altro` and `segreteria` and keep the other mappings as before, you need to declare your enum as:

```
enum professional_role: {
  amministrazione: 1, buyer: 3,
  buyer_audiovideo_consumer_electronics_home_entertainment: 4,
  buyer_fotografia_photo: 5,
  buyer_grandi_elettrodomestici_mda_home_confort: 6,
  buyer_it_information_technology: 7,
  buyer_piccoli_elettrodomestici_sda: 8,
  buyer_telefonia_telecomunicazioni: 9, capi_area: 10,
  comunicazione_hr: 11, direzione: 12, marketing: 13, edp: 14
}
```

If you still want to use your `ProfessionalRole` class, simply add a method that returns the above hash.

For more information, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Will this prevent one from saving a `professional_role == 'altro'` in the future?

Comment: This seems to be best practice: "To remove unused values, the explicit hash syntax should be used." https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 0):

To be able to remove any item from the enum values array without messing up data, convert it into a hash:

```
{
   altro: 0,
   segreteria: 2,
   # and so on...
   direzione: 123,
   marketing: 200,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a `Class` or a `Model` with this `enum`

```
enum piece_status: {
  in_progress:        0,
  available:          1,
  reserved:           2,
  donated:            3,
  sold:               4,
  not_for_sale:       5,
  piece_destroyed:    6,
  archived:           7
}
```

You load it using `concers` (running `rails` `MVC` webapp) this is where you delete the options you would like to hide for `X` or `Y` reason

```
def set_available_piece_status_options
  @piece_statuses_options = Piece.piece_statuses.keys.map{|k| [k.humanize, k]}
  #by default users can not create/update pieces to donated and sold
  @piece_statuses_options.delete(["Donated", "donated"]) # <=== DELETE
  @piece_statuses_options.delete(["Sold", "sold"]) # <=== DELETE
end
```

- Notice how you are using `delete` function from `hash.delete(key)`

Your controller is like

```
  before_action :A, :B, :C, :set_available_piece_status_options, :D
```

*Customize as needed since some pages could require to have all options in the enum you could just create new `concern` method and use it*